# foundation 5.4.6 reveal modal not working

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal

foundation reveal modal just doesnt want to work. Here is my code
    
    
        
    
    
    more

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.reveal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).foundation();
</script>

<div id="edopp" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal>
      <h1>EdOpp</h1>
      <p>Lore ipsum sit amet</p>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
</div>
</body>
```

I cant see what I'm missing here. I've read all the other posts here about reveal and the docs. 
Maybe the jquery version is too old?
Finally is there a way to isolate reveal's css ?

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping your code with the jquery documnet ready that will make sure the codes will run after the page and all doms has been created

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
         $(document).foundation();
     });
</script>
```